# org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreeCreationException: Could not locate TableGroup - model.dao.User(1055362627602899)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a spring boot 2.7.5 with hibernate 5.6.12 project and I wanted to upgrade to spring boot 3.1.0 with hibernate 6.6.2
I'm trying a query count in database for getting total number of records in database
an I get the error

**org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreeCreationException: Could not locate TableGroup - model.dao.User(1057834329991800)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.prepareReusablePath(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3349) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]**

Base class is:

```
public class JPADaoImpl {
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    protected DataSource dataSource;
    
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    
    protected <T> PageData<T> getPageData(CriteriaQuery<T> criteria,Root<T> root,Integer pStart, Integer pSize,LockModeType lockModeType) throws Exception{
        PageData<T> pageData =null;
        try {
            pageData = new PageData<T>();
            
            criteria.distinct(true);
            
            criteria.select(root);
            
            TypedQuery<T> query = getPersistenceQuery(criteria, pStart, pSize, lockModeType);
            
            if (pStart == null || pSize == null) {
                pageData.setData(query.getResultList());
                return pageData;
            }
            
            pageData.setpStart(pStart);
            pageData.setpSize(pSize);
            
            Long rowCount = getRowCount(criteria,root,true);
            pageData.setTotalNo(rowCount);

            pageData.setpCount(rowCount / pSize + (rowCount % pSize == 0 ? 0 : 1));
    
            pageData.setData(query.getResultList());
            
            return pageData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param criteria
     * @param root
     * @param distinct
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected <T> Long getRowCount(CriteriaQuery<T> criteria,Root<T> root,boolean distinct) throws Exception {
        Long rowcount=null;
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
        CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteria=builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        
        Root<?> entityRoot = countCriteria.from(root.getJavaType());
        entityRoot.alias(root.getAlias());
        
        doJoins(root.getJoins(),entityRoot);
        if( criteria.isDistinct()){
             countCriteria.select(builder.countDistinct(entityRoot));
        }else{
            countCriteria.select(builder.count(entityRoot));
        }
        
        Predicate fromRestriction = criteria.getRestriction();
    
        if (fromRestriction != null) {
            countCriteria.where(fromRestriction);
        }
        
        countCriteria.distinct(criteria.isDistinct());
    
        rowcount=entityManager.createQuery(countCriteria).getSingleResult();

        return rowcount;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param joins
     * @param root_
     */
    private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins,Join<?,?> root_){
        for(Join<?,?> join: joins){
            Join<?,?> joined = root_.join(join.getAttribute().getName(),join.getJoinType());
            doJoins(join.getJoins(),joined);
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param joins
     * @param root_
     */
    private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins,Root<?> root_){
        for(Join<?,?> join: joins){
            Join<?,?> joined = root_.join(join.getAttribute().getName(),join.getJoinType());
            doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
        }
    }

    
        /**
     * @param criteria
     * @param pStart
     * @param pSize
     * @param lockModeType
     * @return
     */
    private <T> TypedQuery<T> getPersistenceQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteria, Integer pStart, Integer pSize, LockModeType lockModeType) {
        
        TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
        
        if(lockModeType!=null){
            query.setLockMode(lockModeType);
        }
        
        if (pStart != null && pSize != null) {
            query.setFirstResult((pStart - 1) * pSize);
            query.setMaxResults(pSize);
        }
        return query;
    }

}
```

and the class that extends it

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends JPADaoImpl implements UserDao{
    
    @Override
    public PageData<User> list(User filter, Integer pStart, Integer pSize, List<Order> order, User userAuth) throws Exception {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
        root.alias("root");
        criteria.select(root);
    
        List<Predicate> predicateList = null;
                    
        if (filter!=null){
            
            predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            
            if (!Utils.isEmpty(filter.getStatus())) {
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Byte>get("status"),filter.getStatus())));
            }
        }
        
        if(!Utils.isEmpty(predicateList)){
            criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()])));
        }
        criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("last_name")),criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("first_name")));
        
        PageData<User> pageData;
    
        pageData = getPageData(criteria,root, pStart, pSize);
        
    
        return pageData;
    }

}
```

in UserDaoImpl.list method, JPADaoImpl.getRowCount at line rowcount=entityManager.createQuery(countCriteria).getSingleResult();

I get the error

**org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreeCreationException: Could not locate TableGroup - model.dao.User(1057834329991800)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.prepareReusablePath(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3349) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]**

If I comment line countCriteria.where(fromRestriction); it works ok

It works also in spring boot 2.7.5 with hibernate 5.6.12

Is it a bug in the new version of hibernate?
Is it a workaround to fix this?

Thank you,
Adrian

Comment: Did you find a way solving it?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, you should create separate CriteriaQuery objects for the counting query and the query to retrieve records. Each of these queries should have its own associated Root object. This ensures that the filters in the where statement refer to the correct Root for both counting and retrieving records.

Using the root from a different CriteriaQuery in the where statement of another CriteriaQuery might cause a "Could not locate TableGroup" error. This error indicates that Hibernate is having difficulty determining the correct table group for the query, likely due to the mismatched roots.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the way to fill the predicate and it worked:

```
    Predicate[] predicates = {
        builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("colunm1")),"%" + numeroProcesso.toLowerCase() + "%"),
        root.get("colunm2").in(orgaoJulgadores)
    };

    criteria.where(predicates);
```

for

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("colunm1")),
            "%" + numeroProcesso.toLowerCase() + "%"));
predicates.add(root.get("colunm2").in(orgaoJulgadores));

criteria.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Predicate fromRestriction = criteria.getRestriction();
// hibernate 5.x
if (fromRestriction != null) {
  countCriteria.where(fromRestriction);
}


 Predicate predicateList= new ArrayList();
 // hibernate 6.x
 if (predicateList!= null) {
   countCriteria.where(predicateList);
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I've upgradet to spring boot 3.1.1 so I have hibernate core 6.2.5 but still getting the same error. Does anybody has a resolution? I am stuck with this.

Comment: Hi Todd, in tour code for hibernate 6.x predicateList will always be !=null butt with size 0, obvious. Can you explain or extend your answer? Thank you!